# Setting control points for Cytoscape edges?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm trying to build a descending graph in Cytoscape. I've got the majority done quite well, but now I'm stuck on the edge types. I'd like to use something like the 'segments' curve-style, where my edges have points.

However, instead of being zig-zags, I would like the edges to be constrained to horizontal/vertical lines.

My graph is pretty constrained and the user cannot manipulate the positions. I would like the edges to start at the 'parent' element, go straight down a set amount, then hit a point, turn, head horizontally to the same X as the child, then straight down to the child element.

Right now, the lines go straight, and I can add segments easily, but they aren't constrained and are based on percentages that I won't have access to without doing a bunch of math, which I guess isn't terrible.

Current: 
[image]

Desired:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want specific absolute positions on `segments` edges, you'll need to convert the absolute co-ordinates to the relative co-ordinates that you specify for `segments` edges.

If you want a different type of edges for your usecase, feel free to propose it in the issue tracker.

Comment: It seems that 'ZigZag' edges have been proposed multiple times, but turned down because of a lack of use-case. Wouldn't a strong enough edge case be working with a layout? I'm using Dagre layout, and I can't use the normal workaround (using tiny nodes, and placing those specifically) because my Layout will pick those up and layout the rest of the nodes accordingly. Looks like I'm stuck doing it with the power of maths.

Comment: That wouldn't help with cases like Dagre, because you'd have to calculate the positions from what Dagre returns anyway.

Comment: Zigzag edges can be implemented only if there is a well defined set of properties that determine the visual output, and no such list yet exists.  That list would be formed from real-world usecases and would also have to be sufficiently future-proof

Answer (score 0):

Following on @maxkfranz answer, here's a function which allows you to convert a list of anchor points in absolute coordinates to edge relative coordinates in typescript:

```js
import {array} from "vectorious";

/**
 * Use Matrix power to convert points from an absolute coordinate system to an edge relative system
 *
 * Visually explained by https://youtu.be/kYB8IZa5AuE?si=vJKi-MUv2dCRQ5oA<br>
 * Short version ==> https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1855051/683621
 * @param source Position position of the edge source:  {x:number, y:number}
 * @param target Position position of the edge target:  {x:number, y:number}
 * @param toConvert Array of Position to convert to the edge-relative system
 * @return The points converted to relative coordinates {distances: number[], weights: number[]}
 */
function absoluteToRelative(source: Position, target: Position, toConvert: Position[]): RelativePosition {
  const relatives: RelativePosition = {distances: [], weights: []};
  if (toConvert.length === 0) return relatives;

  const mainVector = array([target.x - source.x, target.y - source.y]); // Edge vector
  const orthoVector = array([-mainVector.y, mainVector.x]) // Perpendicular vector
    .normalize(); //Normalized to have the distance expressed in pixels https://math.stackexchange.com/a/413235/683621
  let transform = array([
    [mainVector.x, mainVector.y],
    [orthoVector.x, orthoVector.y],
  ]).inv(); // Should always be invertible if the ortho vector is indeed perpendicular

  for (let coord of toConvert) {
    const absolute = array([[coord.x - source.x, coord.y - source.y]]);
    const relative = absolute.multiply(transform);
    relatives.weights.push(relative.get(0, 0))
    relatives.distances.push(relative.get(0, 1))
  }

  return relatives;
}

type Position = { x:number, y:number };
type RelativePosition = { distances: number[], weights: number[] };
```

Here i'm using package vectorious@6.1.12 to facilitate all the required matrix and vectors manipulation